# UIActivityViewController is always sharing image before text

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app, I want to share the current song and artist followed by the album artwork. Here is my code:

```
    var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()

    let currentSong = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.title
    let currentArtist = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.artist
    let artwork = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.artwork
    let artworkImage = artwork?.imageWithSize(CGSizeMake(100, 100))

    let shareText = "Now playing \(currentSong!) by \(currentArtist!) via Ryan's awesome app"

    sharingItems.append(shareText) //text first, then image
    sharingItems.append(artworkImage!)

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I choose a share option, like Messges, the image is before the text in the TextField. Why is the image first  if it's last in the array?